# using single sql query how to insert data in three tables which are not joined . or can we insert data into multiple tables which are not joined

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

using single sql query how to insert data in  three tables  which are not joined . or can we insert data into multiple tables which are not joined.

Comment: You need one INSERT per table.

Comment: You might be looking for [a multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) (i.e. `insert all ...`), but it isn't clear.

Comment: Why must this be one statement? Usually you would simply do three separate insert statements and end this transaction with `commit`. If you want all these four commands in one call you may want to write a stored procedure or an anonymous block for this. Just one call, but this would be PL/SQL, not mere SQL then.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INSERT ALL` statement:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/776906/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  a NUMBER,
  b VARCHAR2(20),
  c DATE
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  d NUMBER,
  e NUMBER,
  f TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT ALL
INTO table1 ( a, b, c ) VALUES ( id, 'Table1', SYSDATE )
INTO table2 ( d, e, f ) VALUES ( id, 3, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-23 00:00:00' )
  SELECT 1 AS id
  FROM   DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/776906/1/0)**:

```
| A |      B |                    C |
|---|--------|----------------------|
| 1 | Table1 | 2018-04-23T08:27:37Z |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/776906/1/1)**:

```
| D | E |                     F |
|---|---|-----------------------|
| 1 | 3 | 2018-04-23 00:00:00.0 |
```